# Show contents for subdomain from folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

how can I do something like this: (possibly with .htaccess? or something else, **need the fastest way**)

subdomain:

```
subdomain.example.com
```

shows content from:

```
https://example.com/folder/index.php?name=subdomain
```

what would be the fastest way to do this?

also, do i have to setup anything in ubuntu, apache, or dns?

Answer (score 0):

add a  VirtualHost entry for Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot /folder/index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

change the document root to match your server path